# PHP receber dados de um arquivo CSV via POST com Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, csv

Eu preciso subir um arquivo CSV por meio de um formulário, passar para o PHP usando Ajax, analisar o arquivo e receber um retorno. Já consegui enviar o arquivo, porém não consigo pegar os dados do arquivo para analisar.

Meu arquivo CSV:

```
"nome";E-mail;Data;100;contato@gmail.com;17/01/2021;
```

Meu código:

```js
$("#enviar_file").click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = $('#file').val();
    formData.append('file', file);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        method: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(data) {
            $(".resultado").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
  <button type="submit" id="enviar_file">Upload</button>
</div>
<div class="resultado"></div>
```

Meu código PHP:

```
$tmpName = $_FILES['file'];
$handle = fopen($tmpName['tmp_name'], "r");
$row = 0;
while ($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")){
    if ($row++ == 0){
        continue;
    }
            
    $people = [
        'email' => $line[2],
        'nome' => $line[1],
        'data' => $line[2]),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Por que você não consegue analisar os dados? Acusa algum erro?

Comment: Não consigo pegar as informações com o PHP, fiz um teste e retorna vazio, não consegui verificar se o arquivo CSV está sendo passado corretamente.